# Network extension framework versus kernel extension

Tags: network-programming, filtering, firewall, macos-catalina, kernel-extension

I am looking to implement firewall/network filtering functionalities for macOS.

I am looking at the most secure way to do this, i.e. trying to make sure no network traffic is missed, and that my filtering cannot easily be by-passed.

After searching around, I can see that Apple has deprecated Network Kernel Extension. They recommend now to use the [Network Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension) framework.

However, I can see that firewalls for mac, for example [Lulu](https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html) and [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) have moved to using Kernel Extension, and not the Network Extension framework.

Is there a good reason to do so? Do Kernel Extension allow a deeper, more secure filtering?

Answer (score 1):

> for example Lulu and Little Snitch have moved to using Kernel Extension

I can't speak for Lulu, but Little Snitch at least was developed long before the "Network Extension" API was introduced, it certainly didn't "move to" the NKE API. [According to an article on their own blog](https://blog.obdev.at/little-snitch-and-possible-deprecation-of-nkes/) it looks like they're actively investigating moving to Network Extensions. I suspect that as long as NKEs work without restrictions on all macOS versions they support, they'll keep using those, in order not to have to ship different back-ends simultaneously. But they probably have some kind of internal prototype using the newer APIs already to make sure they're prepared for when NKE APIs are finally removed from the OS.

If Network Extensions support your use case, you should probably go with them. If they don't, you should file Enhancement Requests with Apple, or you will be out of options when NKEs stop working.

**Edit:** To deploy NKEs, you will essentially need a kext signing certificate (Developer ID Application + Kext) if you don't already have one. The alternative is forcing your users to disable SIP's kext signing requirement, which is neither sensible nor reasonable in most cases. I hear Apple has made it much harder to obtain such a certificate in recent years.

Comment: Hi @pmdj Thanks for that. "Network Kernel Extension" have been deprecated. In this blog post, Little Snitch are talking about moving to "Kernel Extension" not "NetworkExtension framework". It is confusing, as the terms are very close.

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood. The important sentence is *"Using the **Network Extension framework** instead of an NKE very likely allows us to build a version of Little Snitch which requires no Kernel Extension at all."* They are specifically talking about moving **away** from a kernel extension; NKE is just a specific type of kernel extension.

Comment: Right, you are correct. However, I believe they have not moved to it yet. Because they are still using kernel extension.

Comment: Yes, this is also what I said in my answer; like I said, LS was created long before the NE framework. Your question implied they moved to NKE from NE; this is definitely not true, the blog post suggests they are planning the opposite. Additionally, LS supports OSX 10.11+, and many key features were added only in more recent versions of macOS, so they would either need to drop support for older OS versions or ship both backends if they moved to NE now.

Comment: If you’re starting a new project from scratch, you have different considerations; if you go with NKE, expect to rewrite it with NE very soon if you want to support 10.16 or 10.17 or whenever they remove NKE APIs. Another issue is code signing: I assume you don’t have access to a kext signing certificate. I have heard they are now fairly difficult to obtain. Apple will likely question why you need it, given they have a non-kext replacement API for NKE.

Comment: Ok, that all makes sense. Seems pretty clear cut in favor of NE. Do you have experience with it? Do you know if it provides as deep and low level functionalities as NKE? Can we have the same depth and security when building a firewall with NE as we had with NKE?